# Using Room Persistence annotation 'RawQuery' for DELETE statement

Tags: java, android-room

Having a method similar to this:

```
@RawQuery
Cursor delete(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
```

by calling it like this

```
dao.delete(new SimpleSQLiteQuery("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + selection));
```

it does not clear the table by selection. This method is used by a `ContentProvider` so I cant use a @Delete annotation and have to write a manual query. Is the functionality related to the return type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Dao Interface you can do it like this:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE selection")
void delete(SelectionType selection);
```

You call the method from an async task.

I would recommend you this [Yt-Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuDihTpkRs6SpZhqgBqPU118) ([This Video](https://youtu.be/0cg09tlAAQ0) is about Dao's)